# How to create a custom timerange and convert it to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, datetime

I want to make a list like this:

```
 list = ['200501','200502','200503'....'202012']
```

I want I could hard code the list from 200501(jan 2005) to 202012(dec 2020) but I would like to do it in a smarter way.

I tried:

```
l = pd.date_range(start='2005-01', end='2021-01', freq='m')
```

and I get a `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>`  with the dates I want.

But now I want to transform it to a list and change `2005-01-31` (that the output format i got) to `200501`

my expected result is `list = ['200501','200502','200503'....'202012']`
I tried to cast l to list but if fails.

What's the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strftime`:

```
out = pd.date_range(start='2005-01', end='2021-01', freq='m').strftime('%Y%m').tolist()
```

Output:

```
['200501',
 '200502',
 '200503',
 '200504',
 ...
 '202010',
 '202011',
 '202012']
```